# Find nodes without particular relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's assume the following situation. We have database with `Person` nodes and `Knows` relations. Finding people that know each other is trivial, but how to write the query that returns all people that particular person does not know? The only way I could think of it was:

```
match (n), (m) where not (n)-->(m) and n.id = 1 return n,m;
```

The obvious downside of this query is cartesian product, so with large amount of data this query would be terribly slow. But is there any other solution possible? I tried with `OPTIONAL MATCH`, but it did not work out as there is no `m` node when r is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

It's technically a cartesian product, but since once side in anchored to an individual node really the search space is just on the `m`.  Have you tried benchmarking the query?

Also, I wonder about trying this:

```
MATCH (m) WHERE NOT (n {id: 1})-->(m)
RETURN n,m;
```